# Np.argmax gives wrong index on prediction class

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I've written so simple handwritten classifier example. It works great, it has %98 accuracy on test samples. However, when I have given an sample input to it, np.argmax gives wrong index (even the ones larger than the size of the classes). Could you help me?

````
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers,datasets,models

os.environ['TFF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'


(training_images,training_labels),(testing_images,testing_labels)= datasets.mnist.load_data()
training_images,testing_images = training_images/255.0,testing_images/255.0

class_names = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

model = keras.Sequential(
    [   
        layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
        layers.Dense(512,activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(256,activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(10),
    ]
)

model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)
model.fit(training_images,training_labels,epochs=5,batch_size=32,verbose=2)
loss,accuracy=model.evaluate(testing_images,testing_labels)
print(f"Loss: {loss}")
print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy}")
model.save("handwritten_classifier.model")


model = models.load_model("handwritten_classifier.model")

img = cv.imread("seven.png")
img = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print(np.array(img).shape)
plt.imshow(img,cmap=plt.cm.binary)

prediction = model.predict(img.reshape(-1,28,28)/255.0)

plt.show()
print(prediction)
index = np.argmax(prediction)
print(index)
print(f"Prediction is {class_names[index]}")```

I've tried reshaping the input matrix but it did not work..
````

Comment: Sorry, off-the-cuff comment as I haven't read your whole code but usually one _minimizes_ loss function (and thus would look for `np.argmin(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this code, and looked at the predictions. They seem to mostly work for me as well as make the right predictions. The cv2 function failed for me, so I used PIL for image processing instead. One reason there could be more classes predicted is if you don't successfully convert to grayscale. In that case the shape could become (4, 28, 28) instead of (1, 28, 28). So, the model will think there is a batch size of 4 and make 4 predictions.

```
from PIL import Image

image_name = "five.png"
image = Image.open(image_name)
img = image.resize((28, 28), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
img = img.convert("L")
print(np.array(img).shape)
plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.binary)

prediction = model.predict(np.array(img).reshape(-1,28,28)/255.0)

plt.show()
print(prediction)
index = np.argmax(prediction)
print(index)
print(f"Prediction is {class_names[index]}")
```

See Colab here - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GsScScPgFdhT5y8RNU1owZaZwzAF0Hjc?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you, it worked! but I couldn't figured out what Image.Resampling.LANCZOS does?

Comment: It’s a method for faithfully creating a lower resolution image. You can use any other one as well, check out the documentation for PIL or any other image process library like cv2.